# Conditional slick-carousel carousel setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Is it possible to only add a setting to something like carousel options if a value exists?

If `arrowsposition` is empty, null etc, instead of `appendArrows` still being used, could I remove that line entirely, so `appendArrows` doesn't try using a value such as `false, null` etc?

```js
var arrowsposition = false;
if (typeof contentblockData === 'object') {
  arrowsposition = contentblockData.data;
} else {
  console.log('No contentblock data available, make sure \'contentblockData\' is available via wp_localize_script');
}

$(this).slick({
  arrows: true,
  dots: false,
  appendArrows: $('.' + arrowsposition + ''),
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can create the settings object first, then add the `appendArrows` property if needed in your `if` statement:

```js
var slickSettings = {
  arrows: true,
  dots: false
}

if (typeof contentblockData === 'object') {
  slickSettings.appendArrows = $('.' + contentblockData.data);
} else {
  console.log('No contentblock data available, make sure \'contentblockData\' is available via wp_localize_script');
}

$(this).slick(slickSettings)
```

Comment: Ah good idea! One issue though, the value is actually a class name, as you'll see in my code it adds the class dot `$('.')` before the value of `arrowsposition `. I am passing slick-carousel a class which to target.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that. I updated the answer for you. Also note that you're passing the carousel a jQuery object, not just a string selector.

Comment: Thank you, now working! :). Any better approach using a string selector or something then? The options you can pass to it are: Selector, htmlString, Array, Element, jQuery object

Comment: If you can pass a selector then the previous version before my edit should work, but if this works for you then I don't see any major problems :)