# Slick carousel: how to change carousel settings on portrait mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I want to make the user be able to swipe the carousel if on portrait mode of an ipad, and not swipe if on landscape mode.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53868087/8147651) example in order to change the settings of the carousel based on portrait/landscape, but it only works to some extent:

**The code below works on page load, but does not work on orientation change.**

I supposed I have to reinitialize the carousel somehow, but I do not know how. I tried to `unslick` it, and reinitialize it with the new settings but it doesn't seem to work.

```
var slickSettings = { /* general settings */ };

    if ($(window).innerHeight() > $(window).innerWidth()) {
        //portrait

        slickSettings.swipeToSlide = true; // user can now swipe

        console.log('portrait');
        console.log(slickSettings);
    } else {
        //landscape

        slickSettings.swipeToSlide = false; //user cannot swipe

        console.log('landscape');
        console.log(slickSettings);
    }

    //initialize carousel
    carousel.slick(slickSettings);

/**
* Does not work
**/
    $(window).on('orientationchange', function () {
            console.log('orientation change');

            if ($(window).innerHeight() > $(window).innerWidth()) {
                //portrait

                carousel.slick('unslick'); //unslick

                slickSettings.swipeToSlide = true; //change settings

                carousel.slick(slickSettings); //reinitialize

                console.log(slickSettings);
            } else {
                //landscape

                carousel.slick('unslick'); //unslick

                slickSettings.swipeToSlide = false; //change settings

                carousel.slick(slickSettings); //reinitialize

                console.log(slickSettings);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You're updating the settings, do you not also need to reinitialise the carousel?

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing with `carousel.slick(slickSettings);`, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I reinitializing it wrong?

Comment: The flow I thought would work is: `carousel.slick('unslick'); //unslick` -> `slickSettings.swipeToSlide = false; //change settings` -> `carousel.slick(slickSettings); //reinitialize`

Comment: May you update the question to include a stacksnippet? Then we could see the bug in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate boolean option to enable/disable swiping would be `swipe`, not `swipeToSlide`.

Also, you should be able to update that one option and refresh the slideshow using the method `slickSetOption`. This would obviate the need for unslick-ing and reloading your slideshow. For example: `carousel.slickSetOption('swipe', false, true)`.

From the docs at https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

> slickSetOption-   **option** : string, **value** : depends on option, **refresh** :
> boolean   Sets an individual value live. Set refresh to true if it's a
> UI update.